# Qt Creator | PySide6 | Ошибка с запуском приложения через Qt Creator

Tags: python, qt, qtcreator, pyside6, pyside

**Примечание:**

1. Версия Python3.9 [Конкретно: Python39_64]
2. Запустить нужно конкретно через Qt Creator - Кнопка: "Запустить" - [Сочетание клавиш: Ctrl+R]
3. Порядок моих действий до ошибки: Файл -> **Новый проект** -> **Приложение(Qt for Python)** -> **Qt для Python** - **Окно (Файл UI)** -> **Запуск** -> **Ошибка**
4. Прошу учесть, сам код, в Qt Creator, ошибками ни как не подсвечивается.

***Ошибка:***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\NameProject\widget.py", line 6, in <module>
    from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide6'
```

***Код [widget.py]:***

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget       #СТРОКА ОШИБКИ - 6
from PySide6.QtCore import QFile
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        self.load_ui()

    def load_ui(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        path = os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "form.ui")
        ui_file = QFile(path)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader.load(ui_file, self)
        ui_file.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

***Код [form.ui]***

```
Вставлять не буду, просто знайте там все норм :< Ибо до туда мои руки не дошли!
```

**Примечание:**

1. Попробовал открыть ПАПКУ с проектом в Visual Code -> Запустил [widget.py] -> Окно запустилось ОДНАКО вылезла ошибка\хрень
2. Прошу помнить: Цель: "Запуск в Qt Creator"
3. Так же, доп. цель: "Возможно ли решить Ошибку\Херь?"

***Ошибка\Хрень:***

```
qt.pysideplugin: Environment variable PYSIDE_DESIGNER_PLUGINS is not set, bailing out.
qt.pysideplugin: No instance of QPyDesignerCustomWidgetCollection was found.
```

Comment: Вот самая главная ошибка `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide6'` - нет модуля PySide6 - надо установить

Comment: Он установлен, pip instal ... и тд все есть

Comment: Проверьте по инструкции https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/gettingstarted.html